# Cannot launch from template in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Working on scripting my first ever EC2 instance launch using the CLI, following the user guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html#launch-instance-from-launch-template).  I manually created a launch template using the console, and am trying to launch an instance from it using the directions provided, but continually get the following error:

```
erich@ip-172-31-69-124:~$ aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-0a0d15f9401ca8442
...
aws: error: the following arguments are required: --image-id
```

I can launch this template manually using the console, and also verify that not only was it launched via template, but it contains the requisite `--image-id`:

```
erich@ip-172-31-69-124:~$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[].Instances[?State.Name==`running`].[InstanceId,ImageId,Tags[]]' --output text
i-061a270a16dd30a7e     ami-66506c1c
aws:ec2launchtemplate:id        lt-0a0d15f9401ca8442
aws:ec2launchtemplate:version   2
```

And if I specify the `--image-id` like it asks, I get this error:

```
erich@ip-172-31-69-124:~$ aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template LaunchTemplateId=lt-0a0d15f9401ca8442 --image-id ami-66506c1c
...
Unknown options: --launch-template, LaunchTemplateId=lt-0a0d15f9401ca8442
```

Curious, why does `aws ec2 run-instances` not recognize that option?

```
erich@ip-172-31-69-124:~$ aws ec2 run-instances help

... 

SYNOPSIS
        run-instances
      [--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
      --image-id <value>
      [--key-name <value>]
      [--security-groups <value>]
      [--security-group-ids <value>]
      [--user-data <value>]
      [--instance-type <value>]
      [--placement <value>]
      [--kernel-id <value>]
      [--ramdisk-id <value>]
      [--block-device-mappings <value>]
      [--monitoring <value>]
      [--subnet-id <value>]
      [--disable-api-termination | --enable-api-termination]
      [--instance-initiated-shutdown-behavior <value>]
      [--private-ip-address <value>]
      [--client-token <value>]
      [--additional-info <value>]
      [--network-interfaces <value>]
      [--iam-instance-profile <value>]
      [--ebs-optimized | --no-ebs-optimized]
      [--count <value>]
      [--secondary-private-ip-addresses <value>]
      [--secondary-private-ip-address-count <value>]
      [--associate-public-ip-address | --no-associate-public-ip-address]
      [--cli-input-json <value>]
      [--generate-cli-skeleton]
```

Well that explains it, but it doesn't explain it.  Where did the `--launch-template` option go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an older version of CLI that does not support `--launch-template` option.

```
$ aws ec2 --version
aws-cli/1.11.109 Python/2.6.9 Linux/4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.7.20

$ aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template
aws: error: argument --image-id is required
```

After upgrading:

```
$ sudo pip install awscli --upgrade

$ aws ec2 --version
aws-cli/1.14.65 Python/2.6.9 Linux/4.1.17-22.30.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.9.18

$ aws ec2 run-instances --launch-template
aws: error: argument --launch-template: expected one argument

$ aws ec2 run-instances help
          [--launch-template <value>]
```

Comment: this worked, thanks!  additionally, i had to install pip with `sudo apt-get install python-pip -y`